# Android Datetime

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to figure out the correct date format in this legacy code base to use. Currently the code is using this format:

```java
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM dd, yyyy K:mm a", Locale.ROOT);
```

The values coming in to be parsed look like this coming back `October 08, 2021 08:15 PM`;

My question is what the heck kind of format is that for the month. I've done some research and I can't find any information on MMMMMMMMM.

Comment: [Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: In other words: `MMM` should be the same as what you see.

Comment: *MMM should be the same as what you see*  ... Well, not really ... 3 is short and 4 or more is full month name

Comment: @Selvin no difference for parsing (but `MMMM` would be correct for formatting) || Patty - try using `Locale.US` or `Locale.UK` - see https://ideone.com/pxhFSo

Comment: (missing in first comment ["**Text:** For formatting, if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, the full form is used; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available. For parsing, both forms are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#text))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved in the comments thanks for the help.